# Can't get data from Access using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, ms-office

I ma using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 x86. I am trying to get data from Access (Office Professional Plus 2013 x64) file, but whenever I run the code error occurs saying

> "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

My Connection string is: `OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Access\Database1.accdb");`

Please Suggest if someone have any idea to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: try going through this - 

http://www.connectionstrings.com/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create an ODBC connection to make this possible.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx